# Docker ports not exposing properly

Tags: docker, tcp, port, couchbase

I have a Docker container (running Couchbase) that requires a lot of open ports. So I have run the container using:

```
docker run -d -p 4369:4369 -p 11209-11212:11209-11212 -p 8091-8092:8091-8092 -p 18091-18092:18091-18092 -p 11214-11215:11214-11215 -p 21100-21299:21100-21299 my-couchbase:latest
```

Which **appears** to run fine. I can navigate to `http://<docker_ip>:8091` and see the admin console, etc.

**However**, when using the Couchbase Node SDK, I can't connect, and instead get a TCP error described [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/error-while-establishing-tcp-connection/1340), which suggests a port is not exposed. To check the open ports, I ran `nmap -v 192.168.99.100` (my docker IP), and don't see anything open! *How can this be?*

**Does anyone have any idea how to verify whether ports are open correctly on a docker container?** I am at a loss here.

A quick `docker ps` shows:

```
5ca8ab8624b  my-couchbase:latest  "run_couchbase.sh"  18 minutes ago   Up 18 minutes  0.0.0.0:4369->4369/tcp, 9100-9105/tcp, 9998-9999/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8091-8092->8091-8092/tcp, 0.0.0.0:11209-11212->11209-11212/tcp, 0.0.0.0:11214-11215->11214-11215/tcp, 0.0.0.0:18091-18092->18091-18092/tcp, 11207/tcp, 0.0.0.0:21100-21199->21100-21199/tcp, 21200-21299/tcp   pensive_aryabhata
```

**Update**:

After running `netstat -nat` from *inside* the running container, I get:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11209           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11210           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35914         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11211           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18091           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11212           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42412           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:18092           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21100           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11213         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:21101           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:11214           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11215         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:45936           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4369            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8091            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8092            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:8091         192.168.99.1:54781      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35369         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:41219         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:35333         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:39544         127.0.0.1:8091          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8091          127.0.0.1:39542         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:21100         127.0.0.1:40371         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54793         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4369          127.0.0.1:56063         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11213         127.0.0.1:55322         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:55326         127.0.0.1:11213         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45342         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:54793         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8091          127.0.0.1:39544         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:58125         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:38466         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:53351         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40371         127.0.0.1:21100         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:38466         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11213         127.0.0.1:55326         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52594         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:35333         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:41219         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:54662         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:35369         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54662         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53351         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:45342         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:60332         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4369          127.0.0.1:45406         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:36552         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:55322         127.0.0.1:11213         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36552         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:36924         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36924         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:56063         127.0.0.1:4369          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:60332         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:52594         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:36954         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45406         127.0.0.1:4369          ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.2:8091         192.168.99.1:54762      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:36954         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53658         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:11209         127.0.0.1:53658         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:58125         127.0.0.1:11209         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:39542         127.0.0.1:8091          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::34781                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::37055                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::11211                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::11212                :::*                    LISTEN
```

I'm not sure how helpful this is though...

**Update 2**:

Per @jmreicha's suggestion, I sshed into the VirtualBox (Boot2docker, since I'm on OSX) and ran the same `netstat -nat` command:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 10.0.2.15:22            10.0.2.2:56257          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 :::21104                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21136                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21168                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21105                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21137                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21169                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21106                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21138                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21170                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21107                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21139                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21171                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21108                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21140                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21172                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21109                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21141                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21173                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21110                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21142                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21174                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21111                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21143                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21175                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21112                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21144                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21176                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21113                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21145                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21177                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21114                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21146                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21178                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::8091                 :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21115                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21147                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21179                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21116                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21148                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21180                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::8092                 :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21117                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21149                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21181                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21118                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21150                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21182                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21119                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21151                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21183                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21120                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21152                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21184                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21121                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21153                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21185                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21122                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21154                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21186                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21123                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21187                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21155                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21124                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21156                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21188                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21125                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21157                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21189                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21126                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21158                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21190                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21127                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21159                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21191                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21128                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21192                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21160                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::2376                 :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::11209                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21129                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21161                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21193                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::11210                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21130                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21162                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21194                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::11211                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::18091                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21131                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21163                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21195                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::11212                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::18092                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21132                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21100                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21164                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21196                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21101                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21133                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21165                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21197                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21102                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21134                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21166                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21198                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::11214                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::11215                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21103                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21135                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21167                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 :::21199                :::*                    LISTEN      
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.99.100:2376 ::ffff:192.168.99.1:56244 ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.99.100:2376 ::ffff:192.168.99.1:54634 ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.99.100:2376 ::ffff:192.168.99.1:54633 ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.99.100:2376 ::ffff:192.168.99.1:64885 ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:192.168.99.100:2376 ::ffff:192.168.99.1:49393 ESTABLISHED
```

And this looks like there are none of the ports exposed? So perhaps we diagnosed the issue??? Now, need to figure out how to solve it...

Comment: What does the output of `docker ps` show?  There should be some information about ports from this command.  Also, did you expose all of the ports in your Dockerfile?

Comment: @jmreicha i just updated the question with that info.

Comment: The port mappings look ok other than a few ports that aren't mapped (21200-21299/tcp, 11207/tcp and 9100-9105/tcp).  Is this docker-machine?  Can you SSH to it and see if the ports are listening/open?

Comment: @jmreicha The unmapped ports are left over from the `Dockerfile`'s `EXPOSE`s. I have updated the question with the output of `netstat -nat` from inside the container. Anything helpful in that info?

Comment: Are you using a VM for your Docker containers?  See if you can get inside the VM and run the netstat command to see if those same ports are exposed to the OS.  If you see the same ports open, there might be network blockage between the VM and your host OS.

Comment: @jmreicha I'm on OSX, so yes, its backed by a VirtualBox. I just updated the question (Update 2) with the `netstat` output from inside the VirtualBox (but outside the docker container). Looks like none of the ports are open. This matches what I saw with `nmap` from my host machine. Question now is: how can we solve this?

Comment: Not that it will get to the root of this issue, bu have you looked at https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/?  Docker is trying to move away from Vbox and Boot2docker.  I guess what I'm saying is it might be easier to switch than to continue diagnosing and troubleshooting.

Comment: This page https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/ explains the migration a little bit more.

Comment: With that many ports open, you may just want to do `--net=host` to remove the network isolation and skip the port exposing. There's a non-trivial overhead _per port_ so when you open a large range, things can start to break.

Comment: @BMitch Where would I add `--net=host`? To the `docker run ...`?

Comment: Yes add it to your run command.  `docker run --net=host ...`

Comment: @Brett `docker run` is not exposing port 8093. That is the query port used for CRUD objects in Couchbase. Have you tried opening that port? http://blog.couchbase.com/2016/june/microservices-wildfly-swarm-docker-couchbase shows a sample on how to run a simple Java application against Couchbase.